# Any pre-packaged PySide for RHEL?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6

I would like to install [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) on RHEL 6.3.

I have found [an RPM for PySide](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=pyside)

Based on my system info:

```
[tbrannon@oc2417102872 Documents]$ uname -m
x86_64
[tbrannon@oc2417102872 Documents]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.3 (Santiago)
```

How do I obtain and install this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no native builds of this library in RHEL6. However you can install [EPEL](http://fedora.mirror.nexicom.net/epel/6/i386/repoview/epel-release.html) repo to find the Python bindings for Qt3.

The repo you found is for Mandriva system and would not work on RHEL.

You can search all rpms containing 'PyQt'
`yum search PyQt`

The first one is listed as: `PyQt.x86_64 : Python bindings for Qt3`

To install it run: `yum install PyQt`

The best option is to download the original package from the Qt website and build it yourself: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Also for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyside